# How to do something like : If not %var1%==%var2% goto fail (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a password protected notepad style thing
UPDATED CODE:

```
:login
cls
Echo Welcome %Name%
Echo Please enter your password
set/p %passin%=
if "%passin%" neq "%pass%" goto :menu
echo Correct password.
pause
goto :menu

:loginfail
echo incorrect password, you have (%loginfails%) attempts remaining
[INSERT SCRIPT FOR CHANGING THAT NUMBER AND SOME METHOD OF SECURITY WHEN IT HITS ZERO HERE]
pause
cls
goto :login
```

However, after the `set/p` it automatically closes, even if I put in the right password which I setup a loading script earlier in the file.

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

EDIT : its no longer closing out after entering password, but no matter what it thinks the password is correct. how could i fix this (when i have echo on, it says if "" == "" goto :menu
(

EDIT2 : i used neq as a commentor says, opposite results, still doesnt work

Comment: I congratulate you in providing a minimal example; however in doing so, and based on your incorrect use of `Set /P` and `If`, there may be several other issues with your code. _Your use of `If` should be utilising doublequotes, `If Not "%passin%"=="%pass%" ...`_.

Comment: now its not caring what the password is, its just progressing on with the script

Comment: Aside from other comments, your logic fails, change to `if "%passin%" neq "%pass%" goto :loginfail`

Comment: i changed it to neq, the new code seems to think every password is wrong

Comment: If that's your new code, what happened to the advice @Mofi provided in their 2nd comment? _Because, as I implied previously, unless the value of %passin% is passin, that's your issue_.

Comment: @Mofi I looked at linked answers and i couldnt work out quite what was being said : and i tried neq because of a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting (closure, unexpected terminate of batch file) is because you have written:

```bat
set /p %passin%=
```

which is completely wrong. You had to enter **ONLY** the variable name (without percent signs (`%...%`)).

Have a corrected version of the script you provided us:

```bat
@echo off

set "pass=PASS_YOU_WANT"
set "loginfails=NUMBER_YOU_WANT"
set "name=NAME_YOU_WANT"

:login
cls
Echo Welcome %Name%
set /p "passin=Please enter your password: "
if /i NOT "%passin%"=="%pass%" ( goto loginfail ) else ( echo Correct password. )
pause
goto menu

:loginfail
set /a "loginfails-=1" >nul
echo incorrect password, you have (%loginfails%) attempts remaining
rem [INSERT SCRIPT FOR CHANGING THAT NUMBER AND SOME METHOD OF SECURITY WHEN IT HITS ZERO HERE]
pause
cls
goto login
```

where `if /I` means enable case-sensitivity.

Hope this helps!